# Unable to Edit pom.xml in Eclipse Maven Project - Only Overview Mode Available

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven

**I created a Maven project in Eclipse, but I can't edit the pom.xml file because it's not showing the editing window to add dependencies. It's only showing the overview window when I open it.**

What could be causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Additional information:

I am using Eclipse version 2023-09(4.29.2).
I have tried restarting Eclipse.
I have tried making new project.
I have checked my Window > Preferences > Maven > User Interface settings, and the "Open XML page in the POM editor by default" checkbox is checked.

[This is what my eclipse showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/covbA.png)

Please help!

Comment: I recommend you to try to do changes in the pom.xml directly with text and not with an visual editor. Have you installed any new Plugins? Can you right click on the pom.xml and "Open with" an "Text Editor"? If nothing works, you can workaround this by opening the pom.xml not in Eclipse but in your OS-Explorer with Notepad++ e.g..

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer below as "Answer" so that everybody sees the solution too! :)

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Did you do a fresh installation or an (maybe incomplete) upgrade? Does right-clicking the `pom.xml` file and choosing _Open With > Generic Editor_ work? Please be aware that something like Notepad++ does not show problems and information that an IDE does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to try to do changes in the pom.xml directly with text and not with an visual editor. Have you installed any new Plugins? Can you right click on the pom.xml and "Open with" an "Text Editor"? If nothing works, you can workaround this by opening the pom.xml not in Eclipse but in your OS-Explorer with Notepad++ e.g..